# quisiera saber que libreria Css ocuparon en esta pagina

Tags: javascript, css, css3, web

queria pedirles ayuda ya que no encuentro como duplicar esa animacion y aunque busque el div no encuentro como lo hacen y me ha llamado mucho la atencion esa animacion
la animacion es que el **.** aplasta las demas letras y queda solo una parte de todo el texto

Les dejo un gif para que vean la animacion, igualmente este seria el link de la pagina: https://applaudo.com/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues en los comentarios del HTML dice que usan Gatsby como framework, usarán React y ajá. Para saber qué librería CSS, está complicado, ¿no?

Comment: Servicios como [builtwith](https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fapplaudo.com%2f) te muestran algunos detalles de las tecnologías con las que está construido un sitio web.